# use some ic for driving lcd 1602 instead of bit banging

Tags: character-lcd

So the lcd 1602 interface is pretty complicated,i basically just want to write the data to the pixels but i have no idea how.
my questions:
1.The lcd works at about 270khz so the address "d0-d07" must be working at 270khz
2.what is the data type that the register takes when i choose the dram mode(address or data)?
3.how to access character rom of the lcd?
[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B512Tn6QVgFfVW8wQ0NMVmZlN3M/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your question could do with some improvement. Please add links to datasheets for devices in question. Please fix capitalisation and punctuation in both your title and post as carelessness creates a bad impression of the author and makes reading more difficult. "Hz" for 'hertz' as per SI unit standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. You can go as slow as you want.
2. 8 bits as defined in the datasheet.
3. Write to the cram for character ram. See the datasheet for those addresses.

Comment: the datasheet is a fake datasheet,it's the introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Find the datasheet on HD44780 - it's the controller used in most simple LCDs. That tells you all you need to know.
You can also drive a LCD using a I2C converter, which makes the job much easier and frees up I/O.